# WPF - How to trigger an event for each element(button) in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listbox, listboxitem

I'd like to trigger event for the elemens which is button in a listbox, the view is as below. [It is a listbox with 32 buttons.The purpose is to toggle the button between 0-1 and trigger event for each element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WceCa.jpg)

There are two solutions I am thinking about. The solution one is to set command for each button, it works but the problem is I can't catch a selectedItem or a selectedIndex successfully so that even thougn I know the button is toggled, but I don't know the item index.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbDirection"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Grid.Column="1"
         SelectionMode="Extended"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         Margin="30,26,44,83"
         Style="{StaticResource ListBoxHorz}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemNoBorder}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLineItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonList}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Style="{StaticResource ChangeButton}"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.ToggleDirectionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType= ListBox}}">
        <Button.Content>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding BtnText}"
                     TextDecorations="Underline" />
          
        </Button.Content>
      </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class DigitalIOViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand ToggleDirectionCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand ToggleStateCommand { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<LineButtons> btnlist;
    private LineButtons _selectedLineItem;
    public LineButtons SelectedLineItem
    {
        get { return _selectedLineItem; }
        set {
            _selectedLineItem=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedLineItem");
        }
    }

    public DigitalIOViewModel()
    {
        btnlist = new ObservableCollection<LineButtons>();
        CreateButtonList();
        ToggleDirectionCommand = new RelayCommand(ToggleDirectionAction);
    }

    private void ToggleDirectionAction()
    {
        LineButtons selectedLineItem = SelectedLineItem;
        int lineIndex=(SelectedLineItem!= null && ButtonList!=null)? ButtonList.IndexOf(SelectedLineItem) : -1; 
        if (selectedLineItem.BtnText == "1" && lineIndex == 0)
        {
            ButtonList[lineIndex] = new LineButtons() { BtnText = "0" };
        }
        else
            ButtonList[lineIndex] = new LineButtons() { BtnText = "1" };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<LineButtons> ButtonList
    {
        get { return btnlist; }
        set { btnlist = value; OnPropertyChanged("ButtonList"); }
    }


    public void CreateButtonList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            ButtonList.Add(new LineButtons() { BtnText = "1"});
        }
    }
}

public class LineButtons : BindableBase
{
    private string btnText;

    public string BtnText
    {
        get { return btnText; }
        set { btnText = value; OnPropertyChanged("BtnText"); }
    }
}
```

I cannot get a correct selectedIndex from this code.
The second solution is to use the IsSelected/SelectedItem property instead of button command  binding, I was wondering if there is conflict with the button command binding for item and IsSelected property fot listbox,so we can't use them at the same time, can someone help me out which is the best solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a note, all your `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` settings are redundant. Either they have no effect because the Binding is OneWay (and UpdateSourceTrigger only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings), or it is already the default, as e.g. for the inherently TwoWay Binding of the SelectedItem property. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is not related to the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thanks for you responding. I was initially planing to customize a listbox with a setter property, but found there is no need to do that and the SelectedItem and SelectedIndexare just are ok as the ButtonList can be used as a two-way Binding.

Comment: Why does that matter? Your UpdateSourceTrigger settings are still all pointless, and should be removed.

Comment: Make sense. I have already delete them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I recommend the mvvm toolkit.  Use a RelayCommand<T> and you can give it a method takes your row viewmodel instance. Hopefully giving that a better name.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand

Instead of invoking the command you can iterate those row viewmodels and call that method instead.  It seems odd that you can't just start with your data set up to match what you're trying to do by calling this method though.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I was able to get the selectedIndex with your method and the other methods provided by BionicCode. They both work well. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `Command` property you can set the `CommandParameter` to the current `LineButtons` item (class names should be singular, names of collections use plural):

```xml
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Style="{StaticResource ChangeButton}"
              Command="{Binding DataContext.ToggleDirectionCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType= ListBox}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        <Button.Content>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding BtnText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     TextDecorations="Underline" />
          
        </Button.Content>
      </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Then get the current item, the item that triggered the command, by accessing the command parameter:

```cs
private void Execute(object commandParameter)
{
  var currentLineButton = commandParameter as LineButtons;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks BionicCode for the reminding on the singular/plural names and explation on the CommandParameter, but can you specify how to call Execute in the DigitalIOViewModel constructor, I am new in WPF and have no idea how to associate the Execute method with ToggleDirectionCommand. Thank you.

Comment: You must have an ICommand implementation somewhere. For example, in your code obviously `ToggleStateCommand` implements `ICommand`. Therefore, there *must* be a `ICommand.Execute(object) : void` method. Here you put the code that can cast the command parameter  to the actual type. The Execute method is later invoked by any ICommandSource, for example a Button. You bind the command to the Button.Command. property. The user clicks on the Button and the Execute method is invoked by this Button.

Comment: Follow this link to find a reusable command implementation and examples on how to use it in your view model class: [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) (from [Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern))

Comment: Thanks BionicCode, I was able to get the expected SelectedItem via the commandparameter. Really appreciate your help and sharing, thanks again.